# HTTP POST WITH powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I need to make an `HTTP POST` call from POWERBUILDER 12.5 by calling up the browser.
I wrote this code opens the browser but does not pass the parameters of the post call. Help me I'm desperate.

```
OLEObject l_ole_ie

l_ole_ie = create OLEObject

li_ReturnCode = l_ole_ie.connectToNewObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


RegistrySet( "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", "front.exe", RegULong!, 8001)

lsHeader = "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + char(10) + Char(13)

try
         l_ole_ie.Navigate(asUrl, "navNoHistory","",BLOB(lsParametri),lsHeader)
         l_ole_ie.Visible=1
catch (RunTimeError lo_error1)
                             messagebox("Error",l_ole_ie.Description)
end try
```

explorer is opened with the correct url but the post call does not start

Comment: Top Wiz has a code sample that may help: http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_winhttp.html

Answer (score 1):

Or upgrade to PB 2019 and use the new HTTPClient object.  It supports many HTTP verbs and other useful features.  All supported features of this object are documented on the product manuals: https://www.appeon.com/support/documents/appeon_online_help/pb2019/objects_and_controls/ch02s39.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the 'Internet Service' in the PowerBuilder Help.  The postURL method seems to be what you are looking for.